# В чем различие между методами String codePoints() и chars()?

Tags: java, строки

Писал скрипт по пересчету символов в строке при помощи Stream API и столкнулся со следующей ситуацией.
В классе `String` обнаружил два, по сути, идентичных метода, возвращающих `IntStream`:

- `chars()`
- `codePoints()`

Оба возвращают стрим ASCII кодов символов. Вот здесь вопрос и заключается, в чем их различия? Когда, где и в какой ситуации использовать конкретный метод? И еще вопрос на засыпку. Как получить чистый стрим символов не прибегая к приведению к char вот так:

```java
str.codePoints().mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
```

Или так:

```java
str.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
```

Результат в обоих вариациях идентичен.

Заранее **Всем** спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Некоторые символы в [Юникод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) кодируются двумя 16-битными словами, так называемыми «суррогатными парами».

Для таких символов `codePoints` вернет одно число (кодовую точку) соответствующее паре слов, а `chars` два числа по одному для каждого значения `char` (16-битное слово).

Например, для эмодзи:

```
String s = "";
System.out.println(s.chars().count());      //2
System.out.println(s.codePoints().count()); //1
```

Различие между методами достаточно хорошо выделяется документации:

> [`chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#chars())
> Returns a stream of int zero-extending the char values from this sequence. Any char which maps to a surrogate code point is passed through uninterpreted.
>
> [`codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints())
> Returns a stream of code point values from this sequence. Any surrogate pairs encountered in the sequence are combined as if by [`Character.toCodePoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toCodePoint(char,char)) and the result is passed to the stream. Any other code units, including ordinary BMP characters, unpaired surrogates, and undefined code units, are zero-extended to int values which are then passed to the stream.

> [`chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#chars())
> Возвращает поток дополненных нулями значений `char` из этой последовательности. Каждое значение `char`, соответствующее суррогатам, передается без интерпретации.
>
> [`codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints())
> Возвращает поток значений кодовых точек из этой последовательности. Суррогатные пары, встречающиеся в последовательности объединяются так же как и в [`Character.toCodePoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toCodePoint(char,char)) и результат передается в поток. Любые другие кодовые точки, включая символы из [основной многоязычной плоскости](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)), непарные суррогаты, и неопределенные кодовые точки, дополняются нулями до значений `int`, которые затем передаются в поток.

Соответственно, `chars` всегда будет возвращать значения меньше 65536, в отличие от `codePoints`.

Также можете почитать:

- [What is a “surrogate pair” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903008/what-is-a-surrogate-pair-in-java)
- [Unicode Character Representations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) в документации `Character`
- [UTF-16](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) — кодировка, которая используется для String в Java.
- [Why is String.chars() a stream of ints in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435833/why-is-string-chars-a-stream-of-ints-in-java-8) и [In Java 8, is there a ByteStream class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459683/in-java-8-is-there-a-bytestream-class) — вопросы о том, почему в Java нет специальных классов-потоков для byte и char и почему для них везде используют `IntStream`